# Can we add a onclick listener to the Sales Path on Opportunity?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lwc-dom

The Opportunity Sales Path I'm using is a standard one, and not taking the lwc route to implement the path. Is there a way to listen to any change here by some event listener on my lwc? So far, I have researched MutationObserver, but did not yield the functionality I'm looking for. I'm restricted by the event propagation by the shadow DOM.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_notify_record_update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by wrapping your LWC component inside an Aura Component.

Inside Aura component listen to [force:refreshView](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:refreshView/documentation) with an `aura:handler`. So, whenever the Opportunity record gets updated this event will be fired. And you can communicate with child LWC component using @api methods in LWC Component.

Here is a simple example describing how this works.

*Aura Component:*

*Markup*

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
    <aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{!c.callLWCFunction}"/>
    <c:opportunityReadStage aura:id="mylwccomp"></c:opportunityReadStage>
</aura:component>
```

*Controller*

```
({
    callLWCFunction: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.find("mylwccomp").doSomething();
    },
})
```

*LWC Component: opportunityReadStage*

*HTML*

```
<template>
    <lightning-card  variant="Narrow">
        <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">{message}</p>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

*JS*

```
import { LightningElement, api } from "lwc";
export default class OpportunityReadStage extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    message;
    @api
    doSomething() {
      this.message = 'Stage Changed';
    }   
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply Saroj. My requirement is to show a modal when the user clicks on the next stage but before the stage change is committed to the database.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, you can't hold a standard process.

Comment: Yes, seems so. I'll have to design the path too in a component to make this work. Thank you for looking into this!